# How can i get data from database for dropdownlist in Form in Laravel using laravel collectives?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravelcollective, laravel-localization

I have used usual dropdown list and it's not worked,
when i click the submit button for all the data in the form except drop down value were sent to database.how can i fix it??

Comment: <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Select Medicine</label>
  </div>

  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
    @foreach($medicine as $med)
    <option value={{$med->id}}>{{$med->name}}</option>
    @endforeach

  </select>
</div>

Comment: Show us your code, please. Chances are your dropdown is missing a `name `.

Comment: Code should go in your question, please, not as a comment. You can edit it in.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<select>` is missing a `name="foo"` attribute.

A form will only submit elements with a `name` as part of the request.